# Prove this RV converges in probability

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a Possion random variable with parameter $\lambda \theta$. Show that $X-\lambda \theta \over \lambda$ converges to zero in probability, as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$, in other words $${X-\lambda \theta \over \lambda} \rightarrow ^P 0 , as \lambda \rightarrow\infty$$
note, $\rightarrow ^P$ refer as converges in probability.

I manage to prove this via Chebyshev's inequality, but I am not very happy about the tedious computation of its expectation value. So, any other ways to prove this?

Comment: Divide by theta, not lambda?

Comment: @Lost1 oops.... sorry i corrected it

Comment: Show that the characteristic function of $Y$ converges to $1$ pointwise. Conclude that $Y$ converges to $0$ in distribution and hence also in probability.

Comment: Then can this be done by wlln, in fact it converges a.s.? Approximate lambda by near by integers and show error is small